# Windows 11: How can I change accessibility mouse settings (size, color) on lock screen?

Tags: windows-11, accessibility

We have multiple users on our media center PC which is running on a 4K TV. We've gone through all the users and scaled up the mouse size using the accessibility settings dialog, but then when we lock the computer or switch users, the mouse is tiny and hard to see.

I know some of the old settings can be found in the registry (ie: HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Mouse) but I don't see where the new settings are stored.

For clarity, these are the settings I'm hoping to set:
[image: Accessibility Mouse Settings]